# Access a globally scoped variable inside of a callback function

Tags: php, callback, scope, array-filter

Please see the following function to scan the files in a directory (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497833/php-opendir-to-list-folders-only/6497894#6497894))

```
function scandir_only_files($dir) {
   return array_filter(scandir($dir), function ($item) {
       return is_file($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item);
   });
}
```

This does not work because the $dir is not in scope in the anonymous function, and shows up empty, causing the filter to return FALSE every time.  How would I rewrite this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to explicitly declare variables inherited from the parent scope, with the `use` keyword:

```
// use the `$dir` variable from the parent scope
function ($item) use ($dir) {
```

---

```
function scandir_only_files($dir) {
   return array_filter(scandir($dir), function ($item) use ($dir) {
       return is_file($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item);
   });
}
```

See [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-154) from the *anonymous functions* page.

> Closures may inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be declared in the function header. The parent scope of a closure is the function in which the closure was declared (not necessarily the function it was called from).