# PHP rename directory in every subdirectory

Tags: php, file-upload, rename

Hey Guys im trying solve a tricky issue. Currently i have a folderstructure like this:

uploads/Event-12/1234-Johne-Doe/[…]
uploads/Event-32/1234-Johne-Doe/[…]

So there a many events with their own folder. Within there a subfolders which are named like the id of the user (1234) followed by first and lastname. You can see that Mr. John Doe has a folder in Event-12 and also in Event-32.

But what if John Doe change his name (for whatever reason…). So i have to rename all folders recursively otherwise all links gets broken.

How to do that with PHP. I can easily rename a folder at once by giving the correct path to it. Is there any nice solution to let PHP search for all matching directories?

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all the folder as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497833/php-opendir-to-list-folders-only) and rename the one you want.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'somefile.php');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a recursive function that makes use of `scandir()` and renames each directory that it finds.

From the PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

This being said, I suggest simply using the user ID for your folder names. You should never use a variable that can be updated to name directories and store user data.

Comment: ja, that was exactly what im searching for! ID only wasn't possible because some guys want to search for users folder. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yepp, is this a database driven application? If so, you shouldn't be trying to fix this problem. When you're having a heart attack, doctors don't treat the symptoms :) Your application is screaming for the coding equivalent of a triple bypass.

I would suggest you strip the names from the folders firstly. Rewrite your script to only create folders with the ID (I assume this is unqiue) - this way, it doesn't matter if they change their name.